# Issue with .htaccess paramters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently facing an issue with URL paramters with htaccess while using Apache/PHP.

I have managed to get my url to work as https://staff.domain.com/1928372/ and that works fine, the issue is when it comes to directories (https://staff.domain.com/3047685/humanresource/mydetails). This loads but when you do a refresh it changes to https://staff.domain.com/humanresource/mydetails/?user=1928372. I have included the .htaccess file in other directories by using `RewriteOptions inherit`

My current .htaccess file is:

```
#php_value session.cookie_domain .techspiresolutions.co.uk
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch 404 ^/includes/config.php$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/includes/navigation.php$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/includes/footer.php$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/includes/getPhoneSystemData.php$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/includes/getPhoneSystemData.php1$


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.staff.techspiresolutions.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://staff.techspiresolutions.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^login /login.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ $2?user=$1 [L]




# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression On
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression On
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Regarding `I have included the .htaccess file in other directories by using RewriteOptions inherit` could you please do mention all path details(samples/examples only) in your question, apart with how many and with what contents htaccess files are present in there? Because if you are inheriting then its important to know what's there in other rules file, thank you.

Comment: Sure, the path details at the moment are: Root->humanresource/mydetails with index.php in each of those directories. In the directories such as humanresource and mydetails, the .htaccess file just has RewriteOptions inherit, nothing else.